# Output 'def' headings when using verifier = testinfra

Tags: molecule

I am using testinfra as the verifier, when executing testinfra, it only outputs 'Collected x items 
 followed by the py test file... and [100%] pass.

How do you see all individual items that were tested? Is there an option I have to set?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command molecule --debug